# Como posso mostrar o segundo/próximo valor de um vetor Int? Usando a linguagem Java

Tags: java

Basicamente é um exercício que faz um cálculo pra saber qual charrete vai chegar primeiro dadas as informações que o usuário fornecer (de acordo com a premissa do exercício).

Estou começando agora com Java, estava usando a Linguagem C antes, e lá quando queria mostrar o próximo valor de um vetor eu fazia algo como: (vetor[contador]+1) para mostrar o vetor, na posição contador +1. Aqui no Java isso não está funcionando, e gostaria de saber como fazer isso.

Código abaixo:

```
package exercicio5;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercicio5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
     final int N = 2;
        int aux = 0, cont = 0, numCha[];
        double  distancia[], velocidade[], metros[], tempo[];
        numCha = new int[N];
        velocidade = new double[N];
        distancia = new double[N];
        metros = new double[N];
        tempo = new double[N];
      while (aux < N){
          
          for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
             
        System.out.println("Digite o número da charrete [1-99]: ");
       numCha[cont] = ler.nextInt();
               while ((numCha[cont] < 1) || (numCha[cont] > 99)){
                   System.out.println("Valor Inválido!\nUtilize um valor entre [1 e 99]");
                   System.out.println("Digite novamente o número da charrete: ");
                   numCha[cont] = ler.nextInt();
               }
        System.out.println("Digite a distância da charrete até a chegada em metros: ");
      distancia[cont] = ler.nextDouble();
                while ((distancia[cont] < 0) || (distancia[cont] > 1000)){
                    System.out.println("Valor Inválido!\nUtilize um valor entre [0 e 1000]");
                    System.out.println("Digite novamente a distância: ");
                   distancia[cont] = ler.nextDouble();
                }
        System.out.println("Digite a velocidade da charrete em km/h: ");
     velocidade[cont] = ler.nextDouble();
                while ((velocidade[cont] < 0) || (velocidade[cont] > 50)){
                    System.out.println("Valor Inválido!\nUtilize um valor entre [0 e 50] km/h");
                    System.out.println("Digite novamente a velocidade: ");
                   velocidade[cont] = ler.nextDouble();
                }
            metros[cont] = velocidade[cont] * 0.27778;
            tempo[cont] = distancia[cont] / metros[cont];
                
                aux++; cont++;
       }
        //essa linha abaixo é onde está dando erro no código e é a fonte da minha duvida
          if (tempo[cont] < (tempo[cont]+1)){
             System.out.println("A charrete "+numCha[cont]+" vai chegar em primeiro lugar!");
         } else if (tempo[cont] > (tempo[cont]+1)){
             System.out.println("A charrete "+(numCha[cont]+1)+" vai chegar em primeiro lugar!");
      } else {System.out.println("Ambas as charretes irão chegar no fim ao mesmo tempo!");}
    }


}
}
```

Comment: *eu fazia algo como: (vetor[contador]+1) para mostrar o vetor, na posição contador +1* - não, pra isso vc tem que fazer `vetor[contador + 1]`. Se colocar o `+ 1` dentro dos colchetes, vc pega a posição `contador + 1`. Se fizer `vetor[contador] + 1` vc está somando 1 ao **valor que está na posição `contador`**

Answer (score -1):

Você está tendo um problema na linha onde você compara `tempo[cont]` com `(tempo[cont] + 1)` e `(numCha[cont] + 1)` com relação à decisão de qual charrete chegará primeiro. O problema está na forma como você está usando a variável `cont`.

Quando você entra no loop `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)`, você já está iterando pelas posições `0` e `1` dos arrays. Portanto, dentro desse loop, você deve se referir às posições do array usando a variável `i`, não a variável `cont`.

Aqui está a parte corrigida do seu código com explicações:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    System.out.println("Digite o número da charrete [1-99]: ");
    numCha[i] = ler.nextInt();
    // ... (as outras leituras e validações)

    metros[i] = velocidade[i] * 0.27778;
    tempo[i] = distancia[i] / metros[i];
}

// Agora você precisa comparar os tempos das duas charretes
if (tempo[0] < tempo[1]) {
    System.out.println("A charrete " + numCha[0] + " vai chegar em primeiro lugar!");
} else if (tempo[1] < tempo[0]) {
    System.out.println("A charrete " + numCha[1] + " vai chegar em primeiro lugar!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Ambas as charretes irão chegar no fim ao mesmo tempo!");
}
```

Dentro do loop `for`, usamos `i` para iterar pelas posições dos arrays, e fora do loop, comparamos os tempos diretamente usando `tempo[0]` e `tempo[1]`.

Além disso, notei que você está incrementando `aux` dentro do loop `while (aux < N)`. Isso fará com que seu loop nunca termine, pois `aux` nunca será maior ou igual a `N`. Você pode remover a variável `aux` e simplificar o loop para `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)`. Isso fará com que o código funcione corretamente.